# Installing Lubuntu 17.10 kills my PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, lubuntu, 17.10

I boot Lubuntu install from a USB drive. It detects Windows 7 and I select dual boot option. The PC has two SSDs. The second one is not formatted. Install proceeds and ask to reboot. It hangs and I must force power off (I waited at least 10 minutes). Now the PC will no longer boot, or go into the BIOS.

I tried disconnecting the SSD/USB drives. Nothing works, it's dead. At this point I just want to be able to access the BIOS.

Comment: Is the title of your question correct? Shouldn't it be 17.10 instead of 7.10?

Comment: I'm not sure Lubuntu was around at the time of version 7! More like [version 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu).

Comment: I would check this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147 Please report back, whether the symptoms match.

Comment: Yes it's 17.10 and the PC has an Intel Atom chip. That bug is probably my issue. The problem is that it won't boot anymore, so I can't recover my BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of kills, it is probably dead. Try checking motherboard connections(cpu power main board power) if doesnt work, try another PSU. If not - motherboard. If your mb is dead probably you can get out with a new one and try that one.

Answer (score 0):

There has been kernel update to 17.10 which made impossible to boot from usb. Canonical released kernel fix to this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

If you are unable to install from USB, I would install a system to HDD or SSD in another machine and would try to power up the computer with new drive.
Then I would try to recover the UEFI Bios according to the guide in the link.

Comment: Thanks, but installing a system on the SSD from a windows machine is not an easy task. That's the only other PC available to me at the moment. I don't want to dual boot that machine and all the installers I have found will alter the boot record of the main HDD, not the SSD.

Comment: I used the ISO and installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 on the SSD (I disconnected the HDD). Put the SSD back in the other PC and it still won't boot. POST on MB says 065C

Comment: I would try to recover Bios. Check your motherboard manual for that.